# How to map a large set of number to another set of numbers in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a column of numbers which represent the week number in a year, which start at week 27 in 2020 and end at week 26 in 2021. The week numbers ascend to 53 and then begin at week 1 again in the new year. My goal is to assign this list of week numbers to a set of consecutive integers, basically from 1 to 53.

eg. week 27  = 1, week 28 = 2, ... , week 26 = 53

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Are your week numbers still unique like you seem to imply? I.e. do they repeat locally in the sense that they are two entries from week 27 and do they repeat non locally as in the are multiple weeks 27 e.g. from 2020 and from 2021?

Comment: @user2640045 So they are not locally repeating, after making some adjustments I begin at week 27 in 2020 and end at week 25 in 2021, implying 52 unique weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah nice that makes it easy. You can just make a dictionary with your mapping and then apply it to your week numbers in your dataframe.

### If you're running Python 3.8 or older:

```
week_map_a = {(i+26):i for i in range(1,27)}
week_map_b = {i:i+26 for i in range(1,27)}
week_map  = {a:b for a,b in list(week_map_a.items())+list(week_map_b.items())}

df['week_numbers'] = df['week_numbers'].apply(lambda x: week_map[x])
```

### If you're running Python 3.9 or newer:

This

```
week_map = {(i+26):i for i in range(1,27)} | {i:i+26 for i in range(1,27)}
df['week_numbers'] = df['week_numbers'].apply(lambda x: week_map[x])
```

works too.

Comment: Thank you for this - I still seem to be receiving "KeyError: 25" after running this, tried playing with it a bit but not able to solve the error, unfortunately.

Comment: @Nish That is very odd since I am clearly adding the 25 to the keys. Can you post the code or something that is equivalent to it? That would make debugging it much easier :).

Comment: Running the code as stated returns:  

`week_map =  {(i+26):i for i in range(1,27)} | {i:i+26 for i in range(1,27)}  
stocks['week'] = stocks['week'].apply(lambda x: week_map[x])`  

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'dict'`  

Replacing the | with or then yields the following:  

`week_map =  {(i+26):i for i in range(1,27)} or {i:i+26 for i in range(1,27)}  
stocks['week'] = stocks['week'].apply(lambda x: week_map[x])`  

`KeyError: 25`

Apologies for the formatting - It doesn't seem to enjoy adding linebreaks for some reason

Comment: @Nish Ah sorry the `|` is a new feature in Python3.9. I have added an alternative to my answer now.